# How do I safely cast from a double to an int without any data loss

Tags: c++, int, double

I have a stock selling/buying program, where the user can say how much of a stock they wish to buy and sell. Everything works fine, until the user wants to sell a stock for $4.10 for $5.10. In order to do math easier with the floating point, I convert the double to an int: 10.10 becomes 1010, and so on. Whenever I cast 4.10 to an int, it becomes 409, and the same occurs for 5.10.

The money is stored in a class, Dollars. Inside of this class, when I call a constructor, I can either call `Dollars(int cents): cents(cents) {}` or `Dollars(double dollars): cents(0) { *this = dollars; }`. When the double constructor is used, it uses the following `cents = (int)(dollars * 100.0);` to cast the given double into an int.

I've tried using the `(int)(double)` cast method inside the class to convert into an int, and I've also tried casting into an int before, and using the int constructor, but neither have worked.

I expect the output of this cast to be 410 when I feed it 4.10, but it always comes out to 4.09.

Comment: See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Check out for the [_Money Pattern_](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html). Your customer bookkeepers will be thankful and satisfied.

Comment: Don't use floats for currency. Also `4.10*100` is likely `409.999999...` and conversion to int simply truncates. In this case you will get more precise results by first calling `std::round`

Comment: @Quimby, I wonder, why many folks post their right answers as comments (and so you do too)? this way many questions end up unanswered, while the correct answer is in the comments.

Comment: @Dmitry I expected this answer to get closed as duplicate or something like that. It's only two lines, didn't seem enough for an answer. But you might be right.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use floats for currency. Also 4.10*100 is likely 409.999999... and conversion to int simply truncates. In this case you will get more precise results by first calling `std::round`. It won't solve all rounding errors. There still will be cases where the result won't be correct just because `double` has 52-bit mantissa and `int` can/will be 64-bit if compiled for x64 platform.

The last problem can be sometimes solved by `long double` if there's a support for it. That is `sizeof(long double)>sizeof(double)` which is not guaranteed.

The easiest correct implementation is to simply use `uint64_t` and do all calculations in e.g. cents. Then all math operations are precise. In real-life when a bank calculates interest it rounds the result too, there's no need for floating precision. Correct printing is then:
`cout<<amount/100<<"dollars "<<amount%100<<"cents";`